# How to get SqlDataReader with Dapper?

Tags: ado.net, dapper

I have a web application that uses old school [`SqlHelper`](https://cs-dotnetnuke.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CS_Library/Components/ApplicationBlocks/SQLHelper.cs) class.

I want to create my custom `SqlHelper` which uses Dapper underneath. So, how can I get `SqlDataReader` from Dapper?

Comment: I'm not dapper expert, but dapper is created to work on object layer(it's Micro ORM) and not worried about usual ado.net stuff including SqlDataReader.

Comment: @reptildarat, I know. But I need this for a reason.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is an `ExecuteReader` method that hands you back the data-reader that the connection generated: you can cast this if you know it is actually a `SqlDataReader`. In this scenario, dapper only processes parameters and literal injection.

```
using(var reader = (DbDataReader)
    conn.ExecuteReader(sql, args))
{
    // use reader here
}
```

I am, however, more than a little intrigued as to what you want `SqlHelper` to do that dapper doesn't already do (but better). Genuine question: I like improving the library. If there is a gap, let me know.

Comment: Thanks. Is there is ExecuteReaderAsync as well?

Comment: @user yes - in the .NET 4.5 build

Comment: Actually, SqlHelper class created by Microsoft patterns and practices team in the enterprise library project. Lot of application uses this class and it is very good in performance but this class lack of async support and it is very old(2002). Dapper is very good in performance as well it support async. The great thing about SqlHelper is that we just need to pass connString, SPName and paramters. Now I need to get rid of SqlHelper. So I am converting it to dapper. The quickest way to convert my data access part will be to wrap the internal functionality inside a custom SqlHelper class.

Comment: @user I am familiar with it; I was curious if I'd simply omitted some huge feature set. It doesn't sound like it...

Comment: Is there is an easy way to convert SqlParameter[] to dapper parameters?

Comment: I have some table value parameters as well.

Comment: @user960567 the way to do that would be to write a class that implements ICustomParameters or ICustomParameter - and wrap that. It should work fine. I'm not at a PC, but let me know if you need an example adding later. Dapper works fine with TVPs.

Comment: The one use case I can see is where one has custom mapping needs for SqlXml columns, since one can only get the column as SqlXml (and thus as an XmlReader or XmlWriter) via SqlDataReader.GetSqlXml.

Comment: @MarcGravell I know the post is old but reading your comment about a huge feature set. Using Reporting Services requires a datatable - my application and framework uses dapper. My SP returns fields with names [Due Date] so this does not map to an object as I can not create objects with field names that have spaces  [Due Date] .Maybe I need to be schooled here; so I would like to simply get DT from my sp for use in Reporting Services .. I think for now I will look to execute reader and use dt.Load method. To keep things uniform it would be nice if dapper just returned DT if I wanted it.

Comment: `Unable to cast object of type 'Dapper.WrappedReader' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader'.`

Comment: @MarcGravell this broke in Dapper 2.0.4, in 1.60.6 you could cast it to a `SqlDataReader`, now it fails.  :( Need to use `DbDataReader`

Comment: @Phill ah, yes; it did - I'll update the release notes

Comment: @MarcGravell do you know if it's possible to get directly at the SqlDataReader any longer, at all? DbDataReader is missing some members such as GetDateTimeOffset

Comment: @IsaacAbraham https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31142700/dapper-unable-to-cast-object-of-type-dapper-wrappedreader-to-type-system-data