# Dapper Unable to cast object of type 'Dapper.WrappedReader' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader'

Tags: c#, dapper

Trying to get `SqlDataReader` using dapper but getting the error on the title.
Below is the code:

```
using (var reader = (SqlDataReader)con.ExecuteReader(query))
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            //do stuff here with reader
                        } 
                    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can [see from the source code](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper%20NET40/SqlMapper.cs#L5586), `WrappedReader` is either:

```
#if DNXCORE50
    internal class WrappedReader : WrappedDataReader
```

[Or](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper%20NET40/SqlMapper.cs#L5790):

```
#else
    internal class WrappedReader : IDataReader, IWrappedDataReader
```

Both `WrappedDataReader` and `IWrappedReader` define a `Reader` property that will allow you to get the underlying `SqlDataReader`.  Thus try changing your code to:

```
(SqlDataReader)((IWrappedDataReader)con.ExecuteReader(query)).Reader { ... }
```

Or:

```
(SqlDataReader)((WrappedDataReader)con.ExecuteReader(query)).Reader { ... }
```

That being said, you may want to actually use the original (wrapped) reader for your `using` clause -- that way it will get an opportunity to react to `.Dispose()`.  If you do it that way, you can get the sql reader in the body of your `using` clause and use it from then on.